# ¿Cómo realizar múltiples Join?

Tags: sql, join

Tablas:

```
create table ciudad
(
  id_ci int not null primary key,
  nombre varchar (50)
)

create table paciente
(
  id_pa int not null primary key,
  nombrepa varchar (50),
  ciudad int,
 foreign key(ciudad) references ciudad(id_ci)
)
create table ingreso
(
  id_ingre int not null primary key,
  observaciones varchar (50),
  paciente int,
  foreign key(paciente) references paciente(id_pa)
)

create table medico
(
  id_me int not null primary key,
  nombre varchar (50),
  ciudad int,
  foreign key(ciudad) references ciudad(id_ci)
)

create table asignacion(
  id_as int not null primary key
  medico int,
ingreso int,
foreign key(medico) references medico(id_me),
foreign key(ingreso) references ingreso(id_in)
)
```

¿Cómo puedo mostrar los datos del paciente, la ciudad, el médico y la asignación?

```
select I.nombre from asignacion ASI
inner join ingreso I on ASI.id_as=I.id_in
inner join medico M on ASI.id_as=M.id_me
```

¿Cómo puedo relacionar paciente y la ciudad?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba encadenando los `JOIN`

```
SELECT A.id_as AS asignacionID,
       P.nombrepa AS paciente, CP.nombreciudad AS ciudadPaciente, 
       M.nombre AS medico, CM.nombreciudad AS ciudadMedico 
 FROM asignacion A
  INNER JOIN ingreso I ON A.ingreso=I.id_in
  INNER JOIN medico M ON A.medico= M.id_me
  INNER JOIN paciente P ON I.paciente=P.id_pa
  INNER JOIN ciudad CP ON P.ciudad=CP.id_ci
  INNER JOIN ciudad CM ON M.ciudad=CM.id_ci
```